# Shorten a paragraph by words not characters

Tags: php

I currently have this string to shorten my characters and add a ... to the end.

```
<? $string = $image["description"];
if(strlen($string) > 200) $string = substr($string, 0, 200).'...';
echo $string;?>
```

How can I change my current string to shorten by words and add the ... after?

I tried switching out substr with strrpos, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Why what's wrong with your code ?

Comment: I'm guessing your solution was cutting off paragraphs in the middle of a word, and you wanted it to end after a word instead???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
<?php
$string = "this is a very long string that needs to be cut down to size";
$max = 20; // or 200, or whatever
if(strlen($string) > $max) {
  // find the last space < $max:
  $shorter = substr($string, 0, $max+1);
  $string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($shorter, ' ')).'...';
}
echo $string;
?>
```

Output:

```
this is a very long...
```

The `strrpos` finds the position of the *last* occurrence (in this case, of a space). So by first cutting the string down to the "maximum length", then working backwards to a space, we find what we're looking for.

You could improve this by looking not only for a space, but other punctuation marks (`.,;:"!'`) as well. If that is important for you...

**alternative method**

```
$temp = wordwrap($string, 200);  // cut your string into chunks, but leave words 'whole'
$temp = explode("\n", $temp);    // break the chunks into individual lines
echo $temp[0].'...';             // take the first line and add '...'
```

[note - this alternative inspired by the now-deleted answer of Shankar Damodaran]

**UPDATE** one more alternative - this allows you to choose multiple word separators:

```
$regex = "/^(.{1,$max})(?=[ !?.,;:])/";
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

The regex explained:

```
^            start at the start of the string
.{1,$max}    "any character, between 1 and $max". 
             This is "greedy" - it will match as many as possible
(?=     )    Lookahead: "followed by" (but don't include in the match)
[ !?.,;:]    Any of these characters
             Note that ? and . lose their special meaning inside the []
```

You can also use a simpler lookahead:

```
(?=\b)       Look for a word boundary.
             This will stop at the end of a word, or include the punctuation
             if that fits inside the character count.
```

but I gave the `[]` form so you have more control over the things you want to split on.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, wife just got home. Anyways this worked great. Thanks so much for explaining this for me. I appreciate it!

Comment: How could I apply the function to cut of at other punctuation's such as a period?

Comment: Is this correct?
 `strrpos($shorter, '.'))`
 `strrpos($shorter, '!'))`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = $image["description"];
if (str_word_count($string) > 50) {
    $string = implode(' ', array_slice(str_word_count($string, 1), 0, 50)) . '...';
}
echo $string;
?>
```

This code is for 50 words.
References
[array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: This worked as well, but I'm using it along with TinyMCE and instead so displaying my image and text it displayed the actual html code. Though this will be useful to me in other situations. I appreciate it. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

`str_word_count` sure will help u

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

```
$Tags = 'This is test for count'; 
$word = str_word_count($Tags);
echo $word;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function word_limiter($str,$limit,$tail="..."){
   $strarr = explode(" ",$str);
   $result = "";
   if(count($strarr) <= $limit) return $str.$tail;

   for($i = 0;$i < $limit; $i++){
      $result .= $strarr[$i];
   }

   return $result.$tail;
}

echo word_limiter("The string going to be shorten.",2);
```

I hope this works... :)